# CollectionView.cellForItem returning nil

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I've created a collectionView in Storyboard and then put the Delegate and DataSource methods in an extension to the ViewController which manages that screen.

The collectionView uses a layoutDelegate to show a four-by-four grid of images.  All cells are shown in the grid, so a cell not being visible isn't a problem and they are all instances of the class `imageCVC`, a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`

This all loads without a problem, but I now want to manipulate four random images before passing control to the user.  Mindful that the collectionView may not have fully loaded by the end of `viewDidLoad`, I call the routine that chooses which image to manipulate, `changeImages()` in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.  The function is as follows:

```
func changeImages() {
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let maxChanges = 30
    var imageIndex = 0
    var imageChanges 0

    while imageChanges < maxChanges {
        imageIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)))
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(as: IndexPath(row: imageIndex, section: 0)) as? imageCVC {
            changeCell(cell)
            imagesChanges += 1
        }
    }
}
```

(**EDIT:** Incorporated Sam's suggestion (below), but it still always returns `nil`!)

Unfortunately, whilst the `imageIndex` gets set correctly (so the collection knows how many elements it has), the `cellForItem` call always returns nil.  I've forced the layout at the beginning of the function, but it has no effect.

Please could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```swift
imageIndex = Int.random(in: 0...(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)))
```

The code starts from 0 and goes all the way to the collection view items count, so if the count is 10, the code goes from 0 to 10 including 10 which is 11 items in total. This is probably what is causing the crash since there are only 10 items and we try to access 11 items.

Just change:

```swift
0...(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
```

To

```swift
0..<(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
```

Comment: HI Sam - many thanks for that correction, but it hasn't worked.  If it had been that problem, wouldn't it have only returned `nil` when the imageIndex was 10?  Instead, unfortunately, it's returning `nil` every time I run the code.  But even with that change, it's still returning `nil`.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it appears that the collectionView data is not being loaded until **after** the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` - which seems a little contradictory to me, but hey, I'm sure there's a good reason... - and so I have implemented what I consider to be a work-around.

I've taken the call to `changeImages()` out from the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and put it into the completion segment of a `DispatchQueue.main...`, written in the `viewDidLoad`, as follows:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3, execute: {
    self.changeImages()
})
```

Essentially, I'm giving the system time (0.3 seconds) to complete it's *full* loading of the subviews, rather than actually placing my code at the correct part of the cycle when I *know* that the views have been fully loaded.  A solution but, I suspect, an inelegant one.

If anyone knows how I should be approaching it, I'd be very interested to hear.  Thanks.